# How to order group by values in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have table in my mysql database.

I am storing that user is subscribing some topic.

I would like to print top 10 topic (`targetId`) ordered by subscribers.

Demo:

```
id | targetId
-----------------
1  | A
2  | A
3  | B
```

Result:

```
targetId | COUNT
-----------------
A        | 2
B        | 1
```

My problem is that I dont know how to sort results.

My current query is:

```
SELECT targetId, COUNT(*) FROM subscription GROUP BY targetId LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT targetId, COUNT(*)
FROM subscription
GROUP BY targetId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that in general you should *always* use `ORDER BY` when using `LIMIT`.  Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly undefined, because it isn't clear which records you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you need in order by ascending counter then use below query

```
SELECT targetId, counter FROM
(
    SELECT targetId, COUNT(*)counter
    FROM subscription
    GROUP BY targetId
)A  ORDER BY counter
LIMIT 10
```